# Highlight substrings in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- *I've seen similar issues, but this one is a bit different.*
  **What I want to do:**
  Find a substring in a table, highlight it and hide all others tr's that do not have the substring. It's like google chrome's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> function, show only the tr's that contains the input search substring.

  Here I have a function that can find the substring but does not highlight it, the commented lines are some unsuccessful attempts.

  ```
  function LogSearch() {
  //var x, y, oldHtml;
  $('#inputSearch').on('keyup', function (e) {
  var value = this.value;
      $('#grid > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
          var bMatch = false;
          $(this).find('td').each(function () {
              //oldHtml = $(this).html();
              if ($(this).html().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                  //x = $(this).html().indexOf(value);
                  //y = $(this).html().indexOf(value) + value.length;
                  //$(this).html($(this).html().substring(0, x) + "<span class='orangeText' style='background-color:orange;'>" + value + "</span>" + $(this).html().substring(y));
                  bMatch = true;
                  return false;
              }
              //else if ($(this).find(".orangeText")) {
              //    var fullHtml = $(this).remove(".orangeText");
              //    $(this).html(fullHtml);
              //}
          });
          if (bMatch) {
              $(this).show();
          } else {
              $(this).hide();
          }
      });
   });
  }
  ```

Comment: because you do the match outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your problem. Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/7wzbrf7o/1/

JavaScript:

```
$( "#inputSearch" ).on( "keyup", function(e) {

  reset();

  var v = this.value;

  $( "#grid > tbody  > tr" ).each( function () {  

    var found = false;

    $(this).find( "td" ).each( function () {
      var tdV = $(this).html();
      var ind = tdV.indexOf(v);
      if ( ind != -1 ) {
        tdV = replaceAll( tdV, v, '<span class="highlight">' + v + '</span>' );
        $(this).html(tdV);
        found = true;
      }
    });

    if ( !found ) {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });

});

function reset() {
    $( "#grid > tbody  > tr" ).each( function () {
    $(this).show();
    $(this).find( "td" ).each( function () {
      var tdV = $(this).html();
      tdV = replaceAll( tdV, '<span class="highlight">', '' );
      tdV = replaceAll( tdV, '</span>', '' );
      $(this).html(tdV);
    });
  });
}

function replaceAll( target, search, replacement ) {
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

CSS:

```
.highlight { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter to remove rows that do not match and add a class

```
$('#inputSearch').on('keyup', function (e) {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $('#grid > tbody  > tr')
    .removeClass("high")
    .filter( function () {
      return $(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1;
    })
    .addClass("highlight");
});
```

and the CSS

```
tr.highlight td { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is only the highlight, then use:

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

$(this) is going to be what you want to highlight.